# Contract cannot create new Contract in Quorum

Tags: solidity, web3js, quorum

My main contract called SurveyFactory creates new Survey forms:

```
pragma solidity = 0.5.9;

import './Survey.sol';
contract SurveyFactory {

    address[] public surveyList;
    address public Owner;

    constructor() public {
        Owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function createSurvey() public returns(address surveyAddress){
        Survey survey = new Survey();
        surveyList.push(address(survey));
        return address(survey);
    }

    function getSurveyCount() public view returns(uint) {
        return surveList.length;
    }
}
```

I can get the address of the created contract fine - but it doesnt exist in my network when i search for it.

Code is tested to be working on Ropsten.

Comment: a private contract cannot create a new contract. that what i remember when i tested Quorum

Comment: Hey, check whats in the Quorum node's logs. This seems very straight forward and should work just fine.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the contract can only be seen by the allowed nodes.

Comment: Yes, but this isnt a private contract though. will check the quorum logs :) @MajdTL